# Do we need to worry about encryption in transit if we use Push Down Optimization in ETL tools Informatica etc

Tags: encryption, optimization, push, informatica, transit

In ETL tools, Push down optimization enables processing on the Databases. since data never makes it to ETL server, do we need to worry about encryption in transit? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. Reason

1. Pushdown optimization does all operations in DB side so its safe.
2. Even if Informatica pulls data into its serve, it imports data in binary format and that is not human readable so i do not think there is any risk here.